# angularjs user feedback message on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have a simple AngularJs app (a form) and after user submit some data, I need to show a confirmation message. I need to show the message on a popup like on this page http://ng-admin.marmelab.com/#/posts/edit/12 (click on the Submit button at the bottom 'Save changes') ie show up a popup from outside the window and move up and fade out after 4 seconds.

How can I achieve this ? Do I need to use Jquery for this ?  Can you show me some examples. Can I achieve this by using ng-animate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use jquery and I don't think you can achieve this by ng animate. You can use angular js modules like below.

http://beletsky.net/ng-notifications-bar/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any number of angular 3rd party libs but angular has nothing built in to provide this for you. Here is another toast popup :

https://foxandxss.github.io/angular-toastr/